# How to classify unbalanced classes in image segmentation?

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I'm trying to implement image segmentation for the first time, but I have trouble understanding the data format. As I understand it, my network input is supposed to be an image, so a `(batch_size, width, height, 3)` tensor, and my output is a classification over all the image pixels. I'm using the Pascal VOC dataset, with 20 classes + background. Thus, my output tensor is `(batch_size, width, height, 21)` with a one hot encoded vector as its last dimension.

However, I am facing the problem of imbalanced classes. Because I have a lot more background than classified pixels in my dataset, my network is computing a good accuracy while it classifies everything as background.

On a simple batch of 50 masks, I calculated that I had 20 to 1000 more background pixels than some other classes. My model is outputting a softmax probability. I'm also using a dice loss.

How can I reduce the imbalance ? I thought about multiplying the one hot encoded vector to a weight when it's not a background, but because I have a softmax at the end of my model (so y_hat will necessarily between 0 and 1) I don't think it will change anything. Do I need to change my loss function ?

Or maybe the way I format my data is just completely wrong ? I'm quite lost here, so I'd love to get some help :) !

Comment: If you want to correct the imbalance even at the cost of higher total error rate then you should change the loss function to say that falsely coding as 'background' has higher cost than the other way around

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks ! So do you know if I should use a different loss than Dice loss, or just try to tinker it manually ? I heard Dice loss was widely used in image segmentation, because it's useful to compare areas. But since I'm classifying pixels, I'm not sure it's the same problem

Comment: Maybe a weighted cross entropy loss function would be better ?